# I wanted to build a chrome extension that will update some page but without any popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to build a chrome extension that will update some page (from other source/page) without any popup (the question is silly as I know as I am new in extension dev)

For example, I had my **manifest.json:**

```
{......
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "My chrome extension title"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
     "persistent": false
    },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
......
}
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "pageloader.html" });
});
```

**pageloader.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
      $("#status").append("hello chrome extension");
    })
    </script>
  <title>Page loader</title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id="status">
      </div>
      <p>hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open 'pageloader.html', javascript is just running fine and showing the output in the browser like:

hello chrome extension
hello

But when I run install the extension and clicking on the 'extension' it is opening 'pageloader.html' in the new tab but showing only

hello

I mean, the javascript part is not running. I will appreciate, if someone would show me my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) does not allow `inline` javascript and loading resources like `jquery` from external servers. In order to make it work.

1. Download `jquery` and save it in local directory under extension folder.
2. Move the `inline` javascript in external file and then include this file after jquery.

If you want to relax the default policy : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing